# CORS : allow vs access-control-allow-methods

Tags: http, https, cors, http-headers

What is the difference between `allow` and `access-control-allow-methods`. In what instances would the values in these headers could be different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between 'Allow' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' in HTTP response header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027187/difference-between-allow-and-access-control-allow-methods-in-http-response-h)